# understanding the base-to-derive conversion

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, dynamic-allocation

Hello I am new to C++ and learning the conversion from a base class pointer to a derived class pointer.

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual void method(){
        std::cout << "this is a base class" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived:public Base{
public:
    virtual void method(){
        std::cout << "this is a derived class" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main(){
    Base *a = new Base();
    Derived *b = new Derived();
    a ＝ b
    a->method() 

    Base c;
    Derived d;
    c=d;
    c.method() 

    return 0;
}
```

a->method() will print "this is a derived class"

c.method() will print "this is a base class""

How to understand the different behavior? I kind of understand that `a = b` basically let the compiler know `a` is a `Base` class pointer pointing to `Derived` class, so the polymorphism will work here. But what does `c=d` do in the code?

I am using Xcode..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code does not compile as presented. The `()` after `c` and `d` **cannot** be there in your real code. As for `c = d;`, look up "object slicing."

Comment: According to @Angew's comment see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) please.

Comment: When you use polymorphism like this, 90% of the time you have to use pointers or references for your objects. Smart-pointers best, naturally.

Comment: Thanks @Angew . Why in this case `Base a = new Base`, `Base a = new Base()` and `Base a` work, but `Base a()` doesn't work?

Comment: @Mahone Look up "most vexing parse." Basically, how would the compiler differentiate between `Base createNewBaseObject()` and `Base b()`?

Answer (score 2):

The `c = d` line does what's called *slicing* - it takes the base part of `d` and copies it to `c`, slicing off all the properties of the derived class. This includes any virtual functions defined in the derived class.

If you want polymorphism, you *must* use a pointer or reference.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I am really not good at relating my specified questions to the existing well-known magic words in c++... `slicing` solves my question!

Comment: @Mahone glad I could help! Sometimes in this business the terminology is the hardest part... Google works wonders when you know which words to use.